# SQL Server query for finding some latest records from each ID

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this..

```
ID     City 
-----------------
1      Jakarta 
1      Bogor 
2      Bandung 
2      Surabaya 
3      Solo 
3      Null
```

I want the query would returns:

```
ID     City 
---------------
1      Bogor 
2      Surabaya 
3      Null
```

Any ideas? I need your help.. I used some methods such as `rank` , `distinct`, `max`.. but the result is not what I expected..

Comment: You need some other way to determine which record is the latest. Nothing in your data indicates this. If you had a column like `DateAdded` then you could determine which record is the latest.

Comment: if ou tried something you always should also post what exactly you tried with code (or selects) used. else it looks like for many ppl that you just want us to do your work even if that is not the case and you really have a problem.   In your case I would put up the selects used and what the not expected result you got was

Comment: @Pradhitya check my answer, Is It that what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` with the `ROW_NUMBER`-function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Id, City, Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By ID
                                            Order by Id DESC)
   FROM dbo.Cities
)
SELECT Id, City
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Altough i don't know which column you want to use to determine the "latest" record. Use that in `Order by Id DESC`.

Comment: This won't work with the ID's being the same.

Comment: @Tanner: it works in a way that you only have one row per ID, but it doesn't not work in a way that it returns the latest record per group because OP hasn't shown that column. I've mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: agree, code works fine but it wouldn't guarantee the desired output as you say. I commented before your edit came in. Either way, it's a poor question.

Comment: thanks..i tried your query, but the city of the ID number 3 can not allow Null.. so, the ID number 3 is 'Solo'.. any more solutions?

Comment: @Pradhitya: what means "can not allow NULL"? What's the rule, what's the column you want to use to find the last record? What's the problem?

Comment: This can't be correct without proper ordering. And if you think that `it works in a way that you only have one row per ID` then why are you using partitioning? That way all ranks will be 1...

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: sorry, i don't get it. OP wants one row per ID, this is already done by this query. Of course if won't return the "latest" record because OP hasn't mentioned the column which can be used tpo determine the latest record per ID. That is mentioned in the answer. OP just need to replace `Order by Id DESC` with `Order by RealColumnThatSpecifiesTheInsertionDate DESC`. Note that even if `ID` was a primary key(which it is clearly not), i should not be used to determine the insertion order because it is not guaranteed that `ID_n` is inserted earlier than `ID_n+1`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, never mind. I have just misunderstood your comment. `it works in a way that you only have one row per ID` I have interpreted this as your solution will work only if ID is PK in test data and not as a result of your query.

Comment: Actually, this is a history table.. i want to display the latest record from each ID..it's difficult because there is no "Datetime" field on the table..

Comment: So what is the primary key? In general a history table should always contain at least one datetime field.

Comment: there's no PK on it, just a plain table without any key.. i migrated the data to the new table which contain an auto increment PK and used your query , and the result worked well,